# UserNotificationCenter Delegate not getting called?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

None of the delegate methods `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` or `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` is getting called. I have set the delegate as well and I tried it in another project, same stuff is happening there as well which is a totally different and live project. I have checked the capabilities to see if it has Push Notification allowed and it does.

It was working fine Yesterday evening. Is the same thing happening with others as well at the moment? Though [Apple System Status](https://developer.apple.com/system-status/) says *APNS is Available* but I'm not getting any response or error from APNS server.

Comment: Have you tried adding print function in didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken?

Comment: Yeah print statement, breakpoint everything . Nothing seems to work. Was working fine yesterday and I didn’t change a thing